# Anthurium leaves

Tags: leaves, hydroponic

I have a anthurium that I've only had for about a month.  It is kept in water only, no soil.  Some of the leaves are starting to get brown spots in the middle of the leaves.  Why is that?  I have changed the water once.

Answer (score 1):

Highest chance of spots in the middles of leaves are due to fungal infection. It can be anthracnose, early blight, leaf blight or some other.

There are chances of sunburn as well.

If you can share a picture of the plant then it would be easier to identify.